# Merge arrays based on first value within each array

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, reduce

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var arr = [
[
    "2021-07-31T00:00:00Z",
    "648429a0-00e5-4752-9d84-2857a0ea0787"
],
[
    "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z",
    "648429a0-00e5-4752-9d84-2857a0ea0787"
],
[
    "2021-07-31T00:00:00Z",
    "AAAA"
],
[
    "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z",
    "BBBB"
]
```

]

I'd like to transform this based on the first value (the date) of each array. So if the dates match they will merge into one. So the output I'm trying to get is

```
[
[
    "2021-07-31T00:00:00Z",
    "648429a0-00e5-4752-9d84-2857a0ea0787",
    "AAAA"
],
[
    "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z",
    "648429a0-00e5-4752-9d84-2857a0ea0787",
     "BBBB"
]
```

]

Would be grateful to know what would be the best approach in this instance.

Comment: please add your code. what does not work?

Comment: Use an object whose keys are the first values.

Comment: This is as far as I got but I think the issue is that I'm really stuck on how to best approach it as opposed to code not working.
uniqueDates.forEach((date) => {  
   arrMaster.forEach((item) => {
   if(item[0] == date){
   // do something
   }
   })
  
        }

Comment: @barmar - could I please ask you to elaborate or point me to a page that might outline what you mean? many thanks

Comment: There are hundreds of questions here about merging arrays. Even if you can't find one that's exactly the same, the general ideas should be the same and you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a map to overwrite the values as they are found in the array. Then use `Object.entries()` to create the final array:

```
var original = [ [1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
var final = []
var map = {}

original.forEach(a => {
    if (!map[a[0]]) { map[a[0]] = [] }
    map[a[0]].push(a[1]);
});
Object.entries(map).forEach(e => final.push([e[0], ...e[1]]))
```

Edit: Changed the answer to get all the values

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'm finding however that the output shows as [
    [
        "1",
        3
    ],
    [
        "2",
        3
    ]
]. Is there a way for the array to output like the below (so that both values are included)?
[
    [
        "1",
  2,
        3
    ],
    [
        "2",
        3
    ]
]

Comment: You just need to modify the way data is stored in the map. Edited the answer to reflect this

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks again - will be very useful

Comment: @user2547766 ... though the above approach works, it depends on references outside of the `forEach`'s callback function. In addition it needs two other full iteration cycles (`Object.entries` and `forEach`) in order to accumulate the final result, and, here again, the `forEach` callback needs to know the `final`  reference which is from an outer scope. Thus such approaches never provide reusable functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this reduce approach

```
    var arr = [
    [
        "2021-07-31T00:00:00Z",
        "648429a0-00e5-4752-9d84-2857a0ea0787"
    ],
    [
        "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z",
        "648429a0-00e5-4752-9d84-2857a0ea0787"
    ],
    [
        "2021-07-31T00:00:00Z",
        "AAAA"
    ],
    [
        "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z",
        "BBBB"
    ]
];

arr = arr.reduce((a, i) => {
    if (!a) a = [];
    var found = false;
    a.forEach(ai => {
        if (ai[0] == i[0]) {
            found = true;
            for (var k = 0; k < i.length; k++) {
                if (k > 0)
                    ai.push(i[k]);
            }
        }
    });
    if (!found)
        a.push(i);
    return a;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP's task can be achieved without nested iterations within a single [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) cycle.

The underlying approach is to use a tailored object as accumulator/collector. Such a collector features 2 properties ... `index` which serves as `Object` based map/lookup for grouped arrays where the group key is always the 1st item of each (to be) processed array ... and ... `result` which is going to hold references of the above mentioned (yet to be created) grouped arrays where one does always push the 2nd item of the currently processed array into.

```js
var arr = [[
  "2021-07-31T00:00:00Z",
  "648429a0-00e5-4752-9d84-2857a0ea0787",
], [
  "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z",
  "648429a0-00e5-4752-9d84-2857a0ea0787",
], [
  "2021-07-31T00:00:00Z",
  "AAAA",
], [
  "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z",
  "BBBB",
]];

function collectAndAggregateGroupedArrays(collector, item) {
  const { index, result } = collector;

  let groupKey = item[0];
  let groupedList = index[groupKey];

  if (!groupedList) {
    groupedList = index[groupKey] = [groupKey];

    result.push(groupedList);
  }
  groupedList.push(item[1]);

  return collector;
}
console.log(
  arr.reduce(collectAndAggregateGroupedArrays, {

    index: {},
    result: [],

  }).result
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @user2547766 ... you might check out the late above provided approach/solution.